# On click, nested states execute controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using the UI router for Angular. I have two nested states using the same controller. When I go from state1 to state2 via `ui-sref` click, the controller is called and resetting all my variables. I want the controller to be called only once.

```
.state('GN.state1', {
    url: '/createGNForm',
    templateUrl: 'app/createGNForm/createGNForm.html',
    controller: 'GNCtrl'
})
.state('GN.state2', {
    url: '/newChapter/{chapterID}',
    templateUrl: 'app/createGNForm/createNewChapter.html',
    controller: 'GNCtrl'
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on teleaziz's answer:

```
    .state('GN', {
        url: '/GN',
        abstract: true, 
        template: '<div ui-view></div>',
        controller: 'GNCtrl'
    })
    .state('GN.state1', {
        url: '/createGNForm',
        templateUrl: 'app/createGNForm/createGNForm.html',
    })
    .state('GN.state2', {
        url: '/newChapter/{chapterID}',
        templateUrl: 'app/createGNForm/createNewChapter.html'
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Have an abstract parent state and nest all the states you want to use the same controller under it.